# AttributeError raised while exporting dict as csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm sure I'm just too blind.
With the help of some posts here (thanks to all) I was able to get further down the line step by step.

I read an xls file, move it into a dict (I need to manipulate, i.e. delete some columns later) and write out as csv.

my code:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(args.inname)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# read header values into the list
keys = [sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]
print "keys are", keys

mydict = []
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
        for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
    mydict.append(d)

with open('mycsvfile.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    w.writerow(mydict.keys())
    w.writerow(mydict.values())
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xls2csv.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "xls2csv.py", line 53, in main
    w.writerow(mydict.keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Interesting enough: the "Print "keys are", keys DOES print all the keys correctly ...

Comment: `mydict = []` is a list,  `mydict.keys()` won't work.

Comment: Do you want the output to be a line of the keys of row 1 from the sheet, followed by a line of the corresponding values of row 1, then a line of the keys of row 2, followed by a line of the values of row 2, etc?

Comment: HiI want the first line to have the keys, the value rows should follow (no need to repeat the keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mydict is a list:
Change line `mydict = []` to `mydict = {}`.
Then it crash because in dict structure not exist append method. To append values in dict you can use `mydict = {1:2}` or `mydict[1] = 2`.
The best method to improve your skills in dict is opening python console and try all methods.
Also is possible put list into dict value:

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict['namelist'] = [1,2,3]
>>> mydict['namelist'].append(4)
>>> mydict
{'namelist': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Hi I thought using a dict is the best method to archive what I want to do (read from xls, delete some columns, write to csv. Looks like this is not the case, what would be the "best" method?